# Create dojox datagrid structure layout programmatically/dynamically

Tags: json, datagrid, dojo

I want to create a dojo datagrid with a header looking like this :

[image]

As you can see I want some section headers (Section A, Section B...), containing many "subheaders" (A1, A2, A3... B1, B2...). I get all the data in a json response when I call the page. Then I was able to do two things :

First, get the data in the json to display all the subheaders, like this :

```
var gridStructure = [
    {width:'150px', name:'Table'}
];

for(var i = 0 ; i < response.columns.length ; i++) {
    for(var j = 0 ; j < response.columns[i].sections.length ; j++) {
        var subColumnToAdd = 
             {width:'200px', name:response.columns[i].sections[j].sectionName};
        gridStructure.push(subColumnToAdd);
    }
}

grid.setStructure(gridStructure);
```

And I also was able to display a table like how I want, but not dynamically :

```
var gridStructure = [{ 
    cells:[ 
        [{width: 'auto'}],                 
        [{ 
            name: 'Section A', 
            colSpan: 2
        }], 
        [{ 
            name: 'A1', 
            field: 'col1' 
        }, { 
            name: 'A2', 
            field: 'col2' 
        }] 
    ], 
    onBeforeRow : function(inDataIndex, inSubRows) { 
        inSubRows[0].invisible = true; 
    } 
}]; 

grid.setStructure(gridStructure);
```

Now what I don't know to do is how to mix it, to fill the headers/subheaders with dynamic data. Thanks for your help and advices.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var gridStructure = [
        [
             {width:'150px', name:'Table', rowSpan: 2}
        ]
];

for(var i = 0 ; i < response.columns.length ; i++) {
    for(var j = 0 ; j < response.columns[i].sections.length ; j++) {
        var subColumnToAdd = 
             {width:'200px', name:response.columns[i].sections[j].sectionName};
        gridStructure.push(subColumnToAdd);
    }
}
```

But that is adding the table statically... to make it completely dynamic, you'll still need something (perhaps in the data itself) that specifies the value for colSpan/rowSpan to get it to display properly.

To add the data, you just need to build a json array of your data.  Each item of that array will be an object containing a single item.  Should be straightforward if your data is already in this format, otherwise just create a loop and build the item dynamically.

```
var items = [
    { name: "First", someProperty: true},
    { name: "Second", someProperty: false}
  ];
```

Once you have it, there are many options on how to build stores:

```
store = new Memory({ data: items });
dataStore = new ObjectStore({ objectStore: store });
myGrid.set("store", dataStore);
```

or

```
grid = new DataGrid({
    store: dataStore,
    ...
```

You can use this as a reference/example  https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/datagrid/demo/datagrid-subrows.php